# Performance of Redux vs Local State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I understand that it is best practice to store UI State in its component, and Application State in the Redux store.

But are there performance benefits in storing UI State locally vs in the Redux Store?

Comment: What kind of expensive calculations you expect to have in your app?

Comment: Various but i mean dealing with an open/closed state for example on a dropdown. Is this bad for performance to have it in a global state?

Comment: It's not bad - absolutely, and it's doubtfully that open/close dropdown will occur often enough to care about performance in this exact case. But as usual it is easier to handle stuff like that in state.